# Replace a certain value in python pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to python panda, I am trying to read an excel file and do some calculations and fill up some rows. When I try to fill up the value and print the result, the results is still the same before I assign the value to it.

Here is what I did.

`df.loc[1][13] = 2`

df is just what I got from my excel file like this

`df = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx',header=5)`

I already checked the data in df, they are perfectly fine.

so the original value in row 1, column 13 is `nan`, I want to replace it with a number, such as a 2, but the code above just would not work.

Comment: `df.iat[1, 13] = 2`  https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/10min.html#selection-by-position

Comment: Thanks! It worked! Still I don't know why the way I did it did not work

Comment: Your indexing `.loc[row][column]` is called a `chained assignment`. Avoid it like the plague... https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in this doc https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/10min.html#selection-by-position, .loc method provides selection by label whereas .iloc method provides selection by position. Also, since output of your selection is scalar you can also use .iat method. So, either of the below will work in your case:

```
df.iloc[1, 13] = 2 
df.iat[1,13] = 2
```

In general, I prefer to use one of the .loc or .iloc depending upon whether the selection is by label or by position.

Comment: Thank you! This is really helpful

Comment: It would be really nice if you accept this answer too.

Answer (score 1):

check out the pandas documentation for [iloc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html)

Based on that a very simple example for replacing specifically the value in one given cell could look like this:

```py
import pandas as pd
mydict = [{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4},\
          {'a': 100, 'b': 200, 'c': 300, 'd': 400},\
          {'a': 1000, 'b': 2000, 'c': 3000, 'd': 4000 }]
df = pd.DataFrame(mydict)

print(df.iloc[0,2]) # print original value from row 0, column 2
df.iloc[0,2] = 9 # replace value in row 0, column 2
print(df.iloc[0,2]) #verify replaced value in row 0, column 2
```

Hope I got the question right...